# How to insert space in table cell when generating table dynamically by javascript

Tags: javascript

i wrote a code to test one issue and notice that not being able to add space when generating table with data dynamically by javascript.

i use   to add some space but did not work.

### full code here

```
<div id='table'>

</div>

var array = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}];
var arrayLength = array.length;
var theTable = document.createElement('table');

// Note, don't forget the var keyword!
for (var i = 0, tr, td; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('<span>'+array[i].id+'&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>'));
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('<span>'+array[i].foo+'&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>'));
    tr.appendChild(td);

    theTable.appendChild(tr);
}
//alert(theTable);
document.getElementById('table').appendChild(theTable);
```

looking for suggestion. thanks

Comment: AFAIK text node cannot contain elements (`span`), only plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Unicode character for a space directly:

```
td.appendChild( document.createTextNode( '\u00A0' ) );
```

Can obviously be done a couple of times:

```
td.appendChild( document.createTextNode( '\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0' ) );
// three spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

You can continue the same way you did with td and tr. Create a new span element, then set the innerHTML. `createTextNode` is just for that, text, so the browser won't interpret tags and html entities.

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = array[i].id+'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
td.appendChild(span);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to add some padding.

```css
#table td > span {
  padding-right:20px;
}
```